# Should lifecycle methods in android studio must have a specific sequence?

Tags: android, methods, lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

Should I have to put lifecycle methods, (like onRestart,onResume) in a specific sequence in an android studio project or it doesn't really matter?

Comment: If you're asking about the order of these methods within an activity class, then the answer is it should not matter AFAIK.  The framework will call each method in a specific order regardless of the source code.  But are you asking about something else?

Comment: Do you mean in the class? if so, no it doesn't matter. 
Anyway read more here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: No no need for any order in case of lifecycle methods. But the life cycle operation should have an order which is executed during activity creation to destroy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of methods in source code doesn't affect their functionality.

Just put them in a such order that is clear for you and your team. For example in the order of their calls while activity run.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted! Thank you!